# Reading a specific data from a specific place in a file(C)

Tags: c, file

If I have this .txt file containing Integers :

```
 - //firstRow 14 5
 - //secondRow 5
 - //fourthRow 3
 - //fourthRow 3
```

How can I read **second** **Integer** from the **first row**?
    Thank you

Comment: what have you done so far?  If you're not even sure where to start, begin with opening the file and printing the first line.  Then you can start to figure out how to search the text in the first line.

Comment: Dan, I read the first line. Now I don't know how to get to second integer in first row which can be multi-digit(doesn't need to be single-digit).

Comment: This is how i read it: fscanf(fptr, "[^\n]", file); variable file is type character and now I don't know how to get the second number in first row as a Integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `fscanf(fptr, "[^\n]", file);`

The scanf functions are hard to understand when first encountered.  Your *format string* (2nd parameter) is wrong.  You want something more like

```
int a, b, n;
while( (n = fscanf(fptr, "%d%d", &a, &b)) != EOF ) {
    if( n == 2 ) { ... your code here ... }
}
```

Be prepared to spend time reading the manual.  **man fscanf** is your friend, but takes some time to warm up to.